# Stepper motor stepping sequence analysis

Tags: stepper-motor, magnetics, phase

I'm currently trying to educate myself on the stepper motor. The figure below is what I am trying to analyze.

First I wanted to analyze the step angle for full step operation and half step. Which I got to be 60 degrees for full step and 30 degrees for half step.

Next I wanted give the power sequence of stator windings for one complete rotation in both modes again. I wanted to assume a logic 1 power signal to a phase produces south pole on the stator facing the rotor, but I'm stuck on where to start here, can anyone help with one of the stepping sequences for either full step or half step mode, I'm pretty sure I can figure the other one out once I have an idea of how to proceed

[image]

Thank you in advance, sorry for any missing tags.

Comment: *both modes* <-- can you explain please?

Comment: full step operation and half step operation @Andyaka

Comment: There's numerous videos and web pages out there on how stepper motors work.  It's hard to know what points you don't understand without knowing what you've looked at, and how it confuses you.